# Using md5 with salt encoding in OpenFire MySQL integration

Tags: mysql, cakephp, xmpp, md5, openfire

I need to share CakePHP salt for hashing password to OpenFire server (MySQL integration).

```
  <jdbcAuthProvider>
     <passwordSQL>SELECT password FROM users WHERE name=?</passwordSQL>
     <passwordType>md5</passwordType>
  </jdbcAuthProvider>
```

How can i add some salt in OpenFire(3.10.0) configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
> <passwordSQL>SELECT (SUBSTRING(S_PASSWORD,1,(LEN(S_PASSWORD)-3))) FROM
> t_users WHERE S_USERNAME=?</passwordSQL> 
> <passwordType>sha1</passwordType>
```